# Sql in php not working might be encoding?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

My SQL code works when i do it phpmyadmin but when i run it in my php script it does not return anything i think it might be the encoding(was utf8) so i changed it to ansi but no difference. Might one of you be able to see if there is anything wrong with it?
(it's a script to remove images from a Wordpress post)

The code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` where post_content like'%<img%\>'" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));//THIS IS THE QUERY THAT DOES NOT WORK
$result = $link->query($query);

/*function filter($toFilter)
{
    $pattern = "/<img.*?>/";
    $filtered = "";
    if(preg_match($pattern,$toFilter))
    {
       $filtered = preg_replace($pattern,'',$toFilter);
    }
    return (string)$filtered;

}
*/
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['ID'];
        $toFilter = $row['post_content'];
        $toFilter = (string)$toFilter;

        $pattern = "/<img.*?>/";
        $filtered = "";
        if(preg_match($pattern,$toFilter))
        {
            $filtered = preg_replace($pattern,'',$toFilter);
        }

        $filtered = (string)$filtered;

        $link->query("update wp_posts set post_content = $filtered  where ID = $id;");

        echo 'this works';
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs? It has nothing to do with encoding.

Comment: To be sure that it's not an encoding problem, try to put in your Database non accent character...If the script works fine then it's encoding problem. ELSE you're having a problem in your PHP script

Comment: What about the madams?

Comment: checked the logs couldn't find anything (this is only part of the code. I have error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); on top

Comment: PARDON M'LADY i was not aware that thou would shower us with your grace

Comment: `or die()` is completely useless where it is now. It is completely useless no matter how you use it, but this is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to escape this slash in `'%<img%\>'` (unless your point is to escape the `>`?)
2. Images don't have closing tags (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#edef-IMG) so you might as well look for the starting tag
3. Stay with utf8
4. `$pattern = "/<img.*?>/";` could be simply `$pattern = "/<img.*>/";`. the `*` means 0 or more, while the ? means optional so it's pretty much redundant

Comment: it should be %<img%> then but how would i escape it?(sorry i am still quite new to webdevelopement)

Comment: You don't have to escape it then. If you do that, the pattern is then easier too: `"/<img>/"`

Comment: i am using the lazy quantifier because there are also non image tags in the post and i would like to keep those

Comment: but i would like to remove the whole image tag including the link and everything in it so say <img src  = 'image.com'> should become just an empty string

Comment: The regular expression is more complicate than that... I think you should revise your approach.